# Consume WCF service in winform, how to dynamically set Endpoint element and contract

Tags: .net, winforms, web-services, wcf

I have build a test WCF Service Service1.svc
I have added service reference of the service to my Winform. Its working good and i can easily consume the WCF service in winform. But i got a major problem :

1. When i rename or delete the 'MyProject.exe.config' file. It is showing error ' Could not find endpoint element with name BasicHttpBinding_IService1 and contract ServiceReferenct1.IService1 
   Since 'MyProject.exe.config' file contains binding and endpoint address which i don't want to share with client or anyone.

   Is there any way to dynamically set endpoint element and contract without using 'MyProject.exe.config' file ?
   [image]

App.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <client>
            <endpoint  address="http://svc.phed.net/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

2. How can i change the Default Message shown by service:

   > You have created a service.
   >   To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the service configuration, you can create a proxy manually.

Here is an example:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("YourEndPoint");
                var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<YourInterface>(binding, endpoint);

                YourInterface client = null;
                client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
                client.YourOperation();
```

In above example, I've used the BasicHttpBinding. If you're using another binding, just use the right class, for instance a NetTcpBinding.

If you handle your service in a try/catch block you can be able to handle this error and throw a most friendly message to your client.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Im creating service Object using :
Dim endpoint = New EndpointAddress("http://svc.phed.net/Service1.svc")

        Dim SvcObj As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client("BasicHttpBinding_IService1", endpoint)


SvcObj.GetData(1021)

        SvcObj.Close()

Comment: Is there any way to Close it like, SvrObj.Close()

Comment: Yes, you can close the ChannelFactory. In the examplo I've posted above, you can close it using channelFactory.Close();

Comment: When the service http://svc.phed.net/Service1.svc is accessed from the web Browser, it is showing a default message as i shown in my question. Is there any way to change that message?

Comment: Yes you can, you must include this tag in you Web.config:
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpHelpPageUrl="MyServiceHelp.htm"  />
This tag must be below <behaviors><serviceBehaviors><behavior>
Read more here: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5778651a-b212-438a-b3e8-f7029775d52a/custom-html-help-page-for-httpget-for-an-iis6-hosted-wcf-service?forum=wcf